# Can't get date/time comparison working correctly in rails. Timezone issue.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I am trying to compare a date/time in a table with the current time to see if the item has expired. I've tried a lot of combinations but just can't seem to adjust properly for the timezone. I am in Eastern Standard time.

```
  create_table "admin_messages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "message"
    t.datetime "expires"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

The basic idea is that I can add a message and expiration date and show the messages that have  not expired.

```
application.rb
    config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
    config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
  end
```

I've tried a number of ways of getting the if statement below to work properly to no avail.

```
 helper_method :show_admin_messages
  def show_admin_messages
    $admin_message = ''
    @admin_messages = AdminMessage.all
    @admin_messages.each do |message|
      if message.expires >= Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")

      $admin_message = $admin_message + message.message + "<br>"
      end
    end
  end
```

If I try a couple of variations on Time.now, I get:

```
Time.now 2016-01-19 09:23:08 -0500 
Time.now.utc 2016-01-19 14:23:08 UTC
Time.now.localtime 2016-01-19 09:23:08 -0500
Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)") 2016-01-19 09:23:08 -0500
```

My problem is trying to figure out the syntax for the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
if message.expires.past?
  ## it expired
else
  ## not yet
end
```

Comment: Spoke too soon. I worked with it a bit more and it appears that the app thinks the date is stored in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

First off you almost certainly don't want to set `config.active_record.default_timezone`. The default is utc - with other timezones you'll have issues such as DST making it appear that records were recreated in the wrong order an so on.

For the vast majority of applications the time zone is only relevant when presenting output to users or receiving input. An action such as filtering whether expires is in the past or in the present doesn't depend on this:

```
message.expires <= Time.now
```

will do it.

Event better would be

```
@admin_messages = AdminMessage.where('expires > ?', Time.now)
```

so that you only fetch unexpired messages from the database in the first place.

Comment: I removed `config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` from application.rb. I still have a timezone offset. I changed to the `@admin_messages = AdminMessage.where('expires > ?', Time.now)'` line that you suggested.

If I look in the table via sql, the date is stored as `2016-01-19 12:51:00.000000` . I had set it to 12:51 so that looks right. However, it appears that ruby/rails is converting that to UTC.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying. The expected behaviour is that input from your users is converted to utc before being stored in the db

Comment: One of the big problems I was having was that I wasn't restarting the webrick server.. Once I did that, your solution worked.